# What is the meaning of $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

In Dummit and Foote book Page No. 65.

It is written that

> Prove that  if $H$ is abelian subgroup of a group $ G $ then $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle$ is abelian

**My confusion**: I'm not getting the meaning of $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle$. It looks like a inner product space in linear algebr .

What is the meaning of $\langle H, Z(G) \rangle?$

**My thinking**: If we take $G= ( \mathbb{Z},+)$ and   $B=\{2,4\}$, then $\langle B \rangle= \left\{ 2n + 4m \mid n,m \in \Bbb Z \right\}$, which implies

$$ \langle H, Z(G) \rangle=\left\{\mathbb{H} + Z(G) \right\}.$$

Comment: I think $\langle H,Z(G)\rangle$ means the subgroup generated by the sets $H$ and $Z(G)$. In this case it is simply the product of $HZ(G)$.

Comment: @kabenyuk, I think that the OP is precisely asking what does "subgroup generated by the sets" mean.

Comment: I feel that your first step really should be to find where in Dummit and Foote this notation is defined, and see if you can understand it there. It *will* be defined in the book, and there may even be exercises to help your understanding of it.

Comment: Given what you write, it is clear that you are woefully unprepared to be reading that part of Dummit and Foote. By this point, you should know what "the subgroup generated by a set" means, and the fact that what you write is utter nonsense (sorry, but it is; the notation doesn't even parse) means that you need to go back and actually learn the material that precedes this. We can tell you the answer, but it is plain it won't do any good: you don't have the necessary knowledge to understand it right now.

Comment: I am very sorry for that@ArturoMagidin  But in Dummit and foote book , there is no  any clear explaination given regarding $ \langle H,Z(G)\rangle$ . They had mentioned  about $\langle A\rangle= \cap H$,so i was confused.

Comment: Also they had mentioned $D_{2n}= \langle a,b\rangle$

Comment: They say *exactly* what "the subgroup generated by" means. Hence, the notation is explained. The fact that you cannot connect those facts and explanations with the issue at hand is proof enough that *you have not understood the material up to this point in the book*, and therefore that you need to go back and relearn it. This isn't the fault of Dummit and Foote being unclear: this is the result of you *not understanding the material.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\langle H,Z(G)\rangle $ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by both $H$ and $Z(G)$.

Each element of $Z(G)$ commutes with all elements of $G$. Since $H$ is abelian, each element of $H$ commutes with each other element of $H$, which is, then, all you need to conclude that $\langle H,Z(G)\rangle $ is abelian (as the generators commute).

Comment: okay shaun, that means $ \langle H, Z(G) \rangle=\left\{\mathbb{H} + Z(G) \right\}.$ Am i right ?

Comment: No, @jasmine; it doesn't.

Comment: okay @Shaun then $ \langle H, Z(G) \rangle=?$

Comment: There's insufficient data, @jasmine. That's also another question entirely.